# Draw Directly onto an Image

Tags: c#, wpf

I am starting with WPF, I have a pretty good understanding of Winforms.

What I want to do, is take a bunch of image tiles and stitch them together to create a larger image that I will display in an Image Control.

in Winforms I would do this

```
Bitmap map = new Bitmap(800,800);
using (Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage(map))
{

    for (int x = 0; x<8; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y<8; y++)
    {
        g.DrawImage(bmp[x,y],x*100,y*100);
    } 
}

pictureBox1.Image=map;
```

I didn't test if this would compile or not, but I hope you get the picture of what I am requesting.

I am just looking for a basic understanding of how to do this, so I can work with it and figure it out.

Comment: First idea: Checkout [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx), [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx), and for layout maybe [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx).

Comment: The concept you suggest is the right way to go about it.

Comment: The concept I suggested doesn't work at all, because there is no Bitmap in WPF...  Which is why I am asking.

Comment: Though I could just reference the System.Drawing namespace, then convert it to a BitmapSource

Comment: Yeah that could most likely work, I think I misunderstood your question.  Although it appears that is not trivial as well, I'll delete me answer in hopes someone else can give a better insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the System.Drawing Namespace

Draw on the Bitmap exactly as described in the question.

```
Bitmap map = new Bitmap(800,800);
using (Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage(map))
{

    for (int x = 0; x<8; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y<8; y++)
    {
        g.DrawImage(bmp[x,y],x*100,y*100);
    } 
}
Image.Source=ConvertBitmap(map);
```

Then use this to convert the Bitmap into a BitmapSource

```
public static BitmapSource ConvertBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
    {
        return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                      source.GetHbitmap(),
                      IntPtr.Zero,
                      Int32Rect.Empty,
                      System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
```